# Google Drive API batch request with HTTP

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, postman

these 2 docs confirm that (1) Google drive API can accept batch request, (2) currently Go-client does not have batch-request feature.
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch#java
https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html

I am looking at the example (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/performance#example). I wonder if I can make a batch request with POSTMAN. How to do it? In this example (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/performance#example), is everything below the first "--END_OF_PART" in the HTTP header? How to construct such a batch request in Postman or HTTP in general? Thanks a lot!

The example posted below as well.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.20.0 (gzip)
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=END_OF_PART
Content-Length: 963


--END_OF_PART
Content-Length: 337
Content-Type: application/http
content-id: 1
content-transfer-encoding: binary



POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions?fields=id
Authorization: Bearer authorization_token
Content-Length: 70
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8



{
  "emailAddress":"example@appsrocks.com",
  "role":"writer",
  "type":"user"
}
--END_OF_PART
Content-Length: 353
Content-Type: application/http
content-id: 2
content-transfer-encoding: binary



POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions?fields=id&sendNotificationEmail=false
Authorization: Bearer authorization_token
Content-Length: 58
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8



{
   "domain":"appsrocks.com",
   "role":"reader",
   "type":"domain"
}
--END_OF_PART--
```

Comment: Added postman tag.